# Field label in the Autocomplete not clearing after submit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete

I am working on feature, where user can select an option in the Autocomplete component.

In the parent component I transfer these props:

```
const selectAutocompletedConfig: FilterSelectAutocomplete = {
data: scenariosList,
label: {
  className: 'filter-input-label',
  name: 'Scenario name',
},
field: {
  className: 'filter-select',
  value: selectedScenario,
  disabled: isPending,
  onChange: handleChangeSelectedScenarioAutocomplete,
},
```

};

**data** - is an object with value and label

On the child component I've created local useState to get the selected value, and useEffect to wait for the selectedValue changes.

I can select and search the option, I also can submit the form, but the problem is with the value displayed in the input.

Value in the component useState is cleared and set to ''

Selected value in the parent component is also set to ''

Value displayed in the input is not cleared

```
function FilterDropdown({ label, field, data }: FilterSelectAutocomplete) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState<any>(field.value);

  useEffect(() => {
    setValue(field.value);
  }, [field.value]);

  interface SelectOption {
    label: string;
    value: string;
  }

  const defaultProps = {
    options: data,
    getOptionLabel: (option: SelectOption) => {
      if (!option) return '';
      return option.label || '';
    },
  };

  const handleReset = () => {
    setValue('');
  };

  const handleChange = (newValue: any) => {
    console.log('newValue', newValue);
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  console.log('value', value);
  return (
    <>
      {<InputLabel className={label.className}>{label.name}</InputLabel>}
      {data && (
        <Autocomplete
          {...defaultProps}
          id="controlled-demo"
          // value={value}
          onInputChange={(_event: any, newValue: any) => handleChange(newValue)}
          onChange={(_event: any, newValue: any) => field.onChange ? field.onChange(newValue.value) : ''}
          renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} value={value} />}
          disabled={field.disabled}
          size="small"
          className={`${field.className} autocomplete-filter`}
          isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option.value === value.value}
        />
      )}
      <Button onClick={handleReset}>Reset</Button>
      <div>The current value is: {value ? value.label : ''}</div>
    </>
  );
}

Parent component:

function ScenarioPage() {
    const [selectedScenario, setSelectedScenario] = useState<any>(null);
    const [addScenarioToSlot, resultsAddScenarioToSlot] = useAddScenarioToSlotMutation(undefined);

useEffect(() => {
    // Remove the scenario's slot from the slots list (if was assigned before)
    if (resultsAddScenarioToSlot.isSuccess) {
      const scenario = getScenarioByID(selectedScenario);
      const updatedSlotsList = removeScenarioSlotFromList(selectedSlot);
      addSlotToSlotsList(scenario, updatedSlotsList);

      setSelectedScenario(null);
      setSelectedSlot('');
    }
  }, [resultsAddScenarioToSlot.isSuccess]);

const handleAddScenario = () => {
    const isScenarioName = newScenarioData.name && newScenarioData.name.length > 0;

    if (isScenarioName) {
      addScenario(newScenarioData);
      setNewScenarioData(emptyDropdownValue);
    }
  };

const handleChangeSelectedScenarioAutocomplete = (value: string) => {
    setSelectedScenario(value) as unknown as string;
  };

const handleAddToSlot = () => {
    if (selectedScenario && selectedSlot) {
      // Add the scenario to the selected slot (request to API)
      addScenarioToSlot({ scenario: selectedScenario, slot: selectedSlot });
    }
  };

const selectScenarioSlotConfig = {
    data: slotsList,
    label: {
      className: 'filter-input-label',
      name: 'Scenario SCS Slot',
    },
    field: {
      className: 'filter-select',
      value: selectedSlot,
      onChange: handleChangeSelectedSlot,
      disabled: isPending,
    },
  };

<MuiAccordionUsage title={'Slot Management'} id={'slotManagement'} className="filters">
        <Stack spacing={2}>
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <Box sx={fieldNewScenarioWrapperSx}>
              <FilterDropdown {...selectAutocompletedConfig} />
            </Box>
            <Box sx={fieldNewScenarioWrapperSx}>
              <FilterSelect {...selectScenarioSlotConfig} />
            </Box>
            <Box sx={buttonScenarioSx}>
              <Button variant="contained" sx={{ mt: '23px' }} onClick={handleAddToSlot} disabled={isPending}>
                Add to slot
              </Button>
              <p>selected scenario {selectedScenario}</p>
            </Box>
          </Grid>
        </Stack>
      </MuiAccordionUsage>
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide more code, for e.g. form where you are using the FilterDropdown, and form submit logic?

Comment: This is the filter input, where you can click the 'add to slot' button and connect scenario with slot. You can check it above

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem.

When we submit button in the parent component we will clear this field.value state. It will also changed my autocomplete local state to null.

When we will select any option from the dropdown, it will also change the parent field.value state

```
  const [value, setValue] = useState<SelectOptionInterface | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (value !== null && field.onChange) {
      field.onChange(value.value);
    }
  }, [value]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (field.value === null) {
      setValue(null);
    }
  }, [field.value]);

  const defaultProps = {
    options: data,
    getOptionLabel: (option: SelectOptionInterface) => option.label,
  };

  const handleChange = (newValue: SelectOptionInterface) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  return (
    <>
      {<InputLabel className={label.className}>{label.name}</InputLabel>}
      {data && (
        <Autocomplete
          {...defaultProps}
          value={value}
          onChange={(_event: any, newValue: any) => handleChange(newValue)}
          renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
          isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option.value === value.value}
          disabled={field.disabled}
          size="small"
          className={`${field.className} autocomplete-filter`}
        />
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```